# EXtended WPF toolkit busy indicator

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I am using busyindicator tool of Extended WPF tool kit _busy is busyindicator

```
_busy.IsBusy = true;

// Thread.Sleep(20000);                                
downloadsomedata();

_busy.IsBusy = false;
```

busy indicator is not showing. Though it works when i put whole thing in `BackgroundWorker` but I need to execute other commands only after `downloadsomedata()` execution. Can anyone help me what is happening here? I tried putting only thread.sleep and not `downloadsomedata();` but still not showing progress bar?

Answer (score 1):

The `BackgroundWorker` class has [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx). So, you can execute other commands in the event handler of this event (see the example for this event on MSDN).

## Update

One more example: [Extended WPF Toolkit–using the BusyIndicator](http://brianlagunas.com/2011/10/07/extended-wpf-toolkitusing-the-busyindicator/).

Comment: @АндрейПро, what do you mean? If the operation executes on the UI thread, the UI is frozen. It leads to bad user experience.

Comment: @АндрейПро, do you still have some problems with the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this WPF Progress Indicator which made simple.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPF.ProgressNotifier

This is a WPF control to show the progress of a long (aync) running task

[image: Nuget]

### Installation

Available on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPF.ProgressNotifier/)

```sh
Install-Package WPF.ProgressNotifier
```